# Mapinfo 12.5.1 (64 bit) failing to call *.xlsx workbooks

Tags: mapinfo, error

My company have upgraded to to Mapinfo 12.5.1 (64-bit) this week. It fails to open tables that call *.xlsx files. Those that call *.xls files have no problem. The error for *.xlsx files is as follows:

[image]

If I attempt to open *.xlsx files in this new version of mapinfo (to register them as tables) I get the following error.

[image]

The *.xlsx files I am trying to call/open are not being used by any other application, nor are they located in a read-only directory or similar.

Suggested solutions on this forum to similar errors suggest converting *.xlsx files to *.xls format. We have hundreds/thousands of tables that call *.xlsx files, so this would be a major undertaking. Furthermore, I wonder that this may be something different and specific to mapinfo 12.5.1 (64-bit), as the same tables (from the same location) open without issue on earlier versions (e.g. mapinfo 12.5.0).

I hope someone may have a smart solution... :)

Answer (score 2):

The release notes for the 64 bit version state that:

"*MapInfo Pro is a 64-bit application that can access spreadsheets and tables from Microsoft Excel and
Access. To use data from Excel and Access within 64-bit MapInfo Pro, you must use the Microsoft Office
64-bit driver.
As part of the MapInfo Pro installation process, the 64-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010
Redistributable for Office is installed if the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 32-bit driver is not
already installed on the system. The effect of this is, if 32-bit Microsoft Office is already installed on the
system, the MapInfo Pro installation process will not install the 64-bit Access Database Engine drivers
necessary for 64-bit MapInfo Pro access to Excel and Access.*"

In short, to open xlsx files on 64 bit MapInfo you must have the 64 bit Microsoft Office drivers installed. The [release notes](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapinfo_pro/english/12.5.1/MapInfoProReleaseNotes.pdf) have some additional information on how to determine which version of the Office drivers you have installed and how to concurrently install both 32/64 bit drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your information. My colleagues contacted Pitney Bowes about the matter - my company have a maintenance license for Mapinfo. I'm told that PB have commissioned Microsoft to engineer a fix that lets 64-bit mapinfo open *.xlsx files on a machine with 32-bit office. We have deployed it and it seems to work a treat. PROBLEM SOLVED. I cannot vouch that this fix is available to PB's non-maintained customers... Perhaps others affected should contact Pitney Bowes for similar solution (their support is a freephone number in the UK!).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and received these step by step instructions from Pitney Bowes Support:

1. Download the MS Office drivers from
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255
   The 32-bit version is AccessDatabaseEngine.exe. The 64-bit version is
   AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe.
2. Uninstall the 64-bit Office driver, if installed, and reboot the system. You will already have it installed
   if you have installed MapInfo Pro 64-bit.
3. Install the 32-bit Office 2010 driver.
4. In the System folder (for example C:\Windows\System32), right-click on cmd.exe and select Run
   as administrator.
5. At the command prompt navigate to the folder where the 64-bit Office 2010 driver is located by typing in 'cd' followed by the
   directory then hit ENTER as illustrated in the screenshot below.
6. Type the command and press enter: AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /passive (as illustrated in screenshot below)
   Both drivers are now installed on your system.
7. Restart MapInfo Professional v12.5 64-bit and open xlsx file to double check if it works

After following these instructions I was able to open an excel file, but then I kept getting a "One of yoru object libraries(|) is missing or damaged. Please run Setup to install it." error upon opening Excel. To fix it, I received the following again from Pitney Bowes Support:

Open the registry editor (Start > Run…   then type “regedit”) then look for a registry value called  "mso.dll" under the key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\FilesPaths".  If it is there then delete or rename it.  Close the registry and restart the machine.

After that, everything worked fine.

Comment: You are very welcome to add your signature details into [your user card](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/46510/christy-heaton) which signs every post you make here.